# Using EXSLT dates-and-times module in XSLT 1.0 yields unknown error

Tags: datetime, xslt, exslt

I added the EXSLT dates-and-times module in my XSLT 1.0 file by declaring:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" ... xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="date">
```

This doesn't affect my resulting page, but when I try to call the actual date with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="date:date-time()"/>
```

I receive an "Error loading stylesheet: An unknown error has occurred ()" message when loading my page. 
Does anyone have a suggestion as to what I might be missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer forexplanation and a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

> but when I try to call the actual
>   date with:
>
> `<xsl:value-of
>   select="date:date-time()"/>`
>
> I receive
>   an "Error loading stylesheet: An
>   unknown error has occurred ()" message
>   when loading my page

**This means that the particular XSLT processor you're using doesn't implement EXSLT** (or just the date-time module of EXSLT).

**Here is a small transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
 >
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select="date:date-time()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to any XML document (not used), with the Saxon 6.5.4 XSLT 1.0 processor, the correct result is produced**:

```
2010-05-22T12:49:44-07:00
```

**Solution**:

Either use an XSLT 1.0 processor that implements EXSLT, or pass the current date-time as a parameter to the transformation.

If using XSLT 2.x, just use the XPath 2.0 function **[`current-dateTime()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-current-dateTime)**.

Comment: I would probably have to pass the current date-time as a parameter--what would you recommend to get the current date-time initially?

Comment: @danielle: There should be such a method/function in the programming language from which you are starting the transformation. For example, in C# this is `DateTime.Now.ToString()`